# Failed to start IPv4 firewall with iptables Can't Telnet to port

Tags: port, redhat, centos7, telnet, iptables

I am trying to open specific ports on a Centos 7 server.

I can add them to IP tables no problem but when I try to start IP tables I get his error.

[root@ck21-erp01 ~]# systemctl start iptables.service
Job for iptables.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status iptables.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

When I look at the status I get this error

[root@ck21-erp01 ~]# systemctl status iptables.service -l
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-05-15 17:52:38 EDT; 29s ago
  Process: 4803 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4803 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 systemd[1]: Starting IPv4 firewall with iptables...
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 iptables.init[4803]: iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.21: multiple -p flags not allowed
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 iptables.init[4803]: Error occurred at line: 9
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 iptables.init[4803]: Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 iptables.init[4803]: [FAILED]
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 systemd[1]: iptables.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 systemd[1]: Failed to start IPv4 firewall with iptables.
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 systemd[1]: Unit iptables.service entered failed state.
May 15 17:52:38 ck21-erp01 systemd[1]: iptables.service failed.

I have opened ports 80, 443, 8989, but can not Telnet to any ports

Any info is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Recently I've eliminate this error with the command
iptables-save

but still can not telnet into the open ports

Answer (score 0):

Found it was a port forwarding issue on the Comcast Router.